# Installation of SQL Server 2014 fails on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, windows-server

I am attempting to run a silent installation of SQL Server 2014 with SP1 on Windows Server 2012 R2 core install, although it also fails when using `UIMODE="EnableUIOnServerCore"`:

> (01) 2016-02-05 19:48:33 Slp: Running Action: ExpandInstallFeatures
>   (01) 2016-02-05 19:48:33 Slp: Error: Action   > "Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.ExpandInstallFeatures" threw an exception during execution.
>   (01) 2016-02-05 19:48:33 Slp: Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException: Unable to load DLL 'sqlconf.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sqlconf.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
>
> Error result: -2146233052
>   Result facility code: 19
>   Result error code: 5412

Any thoughts on why `sqlconf.dll` would not be present? Prior to the installation I have run `SqlSupport.msi`.

This server is part of a two-node FCI which is meant for AlwaysOn.

Summary.txt is available at https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=CBCE97C71A32BCAE%21368391.

Comment: The log you posted are not enough to help you out. Use [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) to add output of `summary.txt` in the question. Have you read [Install SQL Server 2014 on Server Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231669%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Comment: There's not much else in the log, but a link is available.

Comment: It seems to me the error is because .Net Framework is not installed or missing. Have you enabled `.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Full Profile` and `NET Framework 4 Server Core Profile`. Please read the link I shared in my first reply

Comment: Yes, both are installed.

Comment: Do you actually reach to installation or the exception is coming while selecting options. If so where you are getting the exception

Comment: This is using a config file, but if I were to use the UI option, it would exit on the screen after selecting the features to install.

Comment: You cannot install SQL Server using GUI on server core. Can you try using command prompt `Setup.exe /qs /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQLEngine,Replication /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSVCACCOUNT="<DomainName\UserName>" /SQLSVCPASSWORD="<StrongPassword>" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="<DomainName\UserName>" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" /TCPENABLED=1 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS`.  Please read the article shared in first link. You seem to be in hurry

Comment: I just said that this was using a config file, I've already gone through that process. You *can* use the UIMode= to enable the UI option on Server Core, but that isn't what I'm attempting to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uninstalling `SqlSupport.msi` allowed the installation to proceed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A reinstallation of the Visual C++ Redistributable 2010 worked for me. 
(https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003)

The bit width should be the same as that of the installed MS SQL Server.